# Scala, websockets and immutable data

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm writing a websocket client using the nv-websocket-client Java library. In order to process incoming data I have to declare a class extending WebSocketAdapter and override several methods (most importantly OnMessage)

```
class Client extends WebSocketAdapter {
  override def onTextMessage(websocket: WebSocket, text: String): Unit = {
        processData(text)
    }
  def processData(text: String): Unit = ???
  }
```

The problem is I have to save some data in between the calls and I don't see how to do it without declaring a var variable in Client. Is there any way to do it in a strict functional style?

PS: I know that akka-http also has a websockets functionality, but I'm stuck with this library, unfortunately.

Comment: No, a library that was intended to be used in a mutable way has to be used in a mutable way. You may write an immutable wrapper over it, but the implementation will always be mutable.

Comment: I would advice you to read more about mutable states in functional style here: https://livebook.manning.com/book/functional-programming-in-scala/chapter-14/

Comment: If your "implementation" (or algorithm) is needs mutability then you either use mutability or change the algorithm.